# The Maclaurin series for $e^{\sin(x)}$ up to the fourth term

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I am trying to get the Maclaurin series for $e^{\sin(x)}$ up to the fourth term, which should be:

$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{8}x^4+o(x^4)\tag{1}$$

This is how I go about it:

$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}(\sin(x))^2+\frac{1}{6}(\sin(x))^3+o(x^4)\tag{2}$$

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^4)\tag{3}$$
$$(\sin(x))^2=x^2-\frac{x^4}{6}+o(x^5)-\frac{x^4}{6}=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+o(x^5)\tag{4}$$

$$(\sin(x))^3=x^3+o(x^4)\tag{5}$$

Then I plug (3),(4) and (5) into (2), which results in:

$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(x^3\right)+o(x^4)=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^4+o(x^4)\tag{6}$$

Which is wrong. Please tell me where I go wrong.

Comment: You forgot the $(\sin^4 x)/4!$ term.

Comment: Oh, right. That's embarrassing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As an exercise, you could try to find the MacLaurin series of $\log(1+e^x)$ and $e^{(e^x)}$. These are not as easy as they seem.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. I'll take a go at those.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, you could do it faster
$$A=e^{\sin(x)}\implies \log(A)=\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^5\right
   )$$

Comment: how did the $x^3$ terms vanish in the final form?

Comment: Could you please expand on how you did the last step?

Comment: @timafo. $e^t=1+t+\frac 12 t^2+\cdots$. Make $t=x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ and expand. It is clear ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Yeah, I get it, thanks. You still gonna have to perform manipulations with the third and the fourth terms though.

Comment: @timafo. You are correct; I just find it simpler. As I wrote *"in my humble opinion, ..."*

Comment: Maybe it is. Thanks for your input.